# workflow on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Complete newbie to GC here: I understand data goes in the google cloud storage bucket and is persistent. Where can I store the actual code I write so that it also persists since anything done on a VM will disappear after it shuts down. Do I create a persistent drive and then mount it each time? Thanks